# How to remove array inside an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filtering, javascript-objects

```
let array = [
    {id: "455", some: [{id: "21"}]},
    {id: "12", some: [{id: "21"}]},
    {id: "12", some: [{id: "21"}]}
];

array.slice("some");
```

Here I was trying to remove an array inside an array but it's not working.

Here I only want to remove `some` array from  all objects.

Comment: `array.map(o => ({id: o.id}))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use rest syntax and some [Object Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring):

```
let result = array.map(({ some, ...rest}) => rest);
```

**Demo:**

```js
let array = [
   {id: "455", some: [{id: "21"}]},
   {id: "12", some: [{id: "21"}]},
   {id: "12", some: [{id: "21"}]}
];
      
let result = array.map(({ some, ...rest}) => rest);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

In one line:

```js
let array = [{id:"455",some:[{id:"21",},],},{id:"12",some:[{id:"21",},],},{id:"12",some:[{id:"21",},],}];


array.forEach(it => delete it.some);

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)  take out only desired property and value.

```js
let array = [{id:"455",some:[{id:"21",},],},{id:"12",some:[{id:"21",},],},{id:"12",some:[{id:"21",},],}];
      
let result = array.map(({id}) => ({id}));

console.log(result);
```